# use syntax in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How can I rewrite the console.log rules using the following
variables.

```js
let blocksGehaald = ["Iron Man", "Pitch Perfect", "One of a Kind"]
let cleGehaald = true
let favoriteBlock = 0
console.log(`Mijn favoriete block is Iron Man!`)
console.log(`Ik heb 3 building blocks gehaald!`)
```

I tried to make a new variable

```js
let a = Iron man
console.log('Mijn favoriete block is ${a} !')
```

I don't get an error but it's not the right answer according to my teacher, I have to use something else

Comment: Accept the answer if the following answer work for you

Answer (score 2):

You need to use back tick if you are using template literals. Also array is 0 indexed base. So to retrieve the `Iron Man` from array you have to pass zero like 
`blocksGehaald[favoriteBlock]` assuming 0 is stored in variable `favoriteBlock``

```js
let blocksGehaald = ["Iron Man", "Pitch Perfect", "One of a Kind"]
let cleGehaald = true
let favoriteBlock = 0

console.log(`Mijn favoriete block is ${blocksGehaald[favoriteBlock]}!`)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let a = "Iron man"
console.log(`Mijn favoriete block is ${a} !`)
```

In Javascript, single quotes (`'`) and double quotes (`"`) are the same.

Ticks (``) on the other hand are different in the sense that they also allow for the use of `${}`.